# Logarithmic y-axis bins in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, logarithm

I'm trying to create a histogram of a data column and plot it logarithmically (`y-axis`) and I'm  not sure why the following code does not work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt('foo.bar')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.hist(data, bins=(23.0, 23.5,24.0,24.5,25.0,25.5,26.0,26.5,27.0,27.5,28.0))
ax.set_xlim(23.5, 28)
ax.set_ylim(0, 30)
ax.grid(True)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

I've also tried instead of `plt.yscale('log')` adding `Log=true` in the `plt.hist` line and also I tried `ax.set_yscale('log')`, but nothing seems to work. I either get an empty plot, either the `y-axis` is indeed logarithmic (with the code as shown above), but there is no data plotted (no bins).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Pyplot Bar Plot bars disapear when using log scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047068/python-pyplot-bar-plot-bars-disapear-when-using-log-scale)

Comment: related problem, different solution

Answer (score 111, accepted):

try

```
plt.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
```

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yscale

The issue is with the bottom of bars being at y=0 and the default is to mask out in-valid points (`log(0)` -> undefined) when doing the log transformation (there was discussion of changing this, but I don't remember which way it went) so when it tries to draw the rectangles for you bar plot, the bottom edge is masked out -> no rectangles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The solution you proposed solved the disappearing bars, but another "bug" then surfaced: all the labels of the y-logarithmic axis were plotted on top of each other. This last problem was solved by commenting the "ax.set_ylim(0, 30)" line.

Comment: yes, because the 0 in the limit is clipped to some very small number so you have an unreasonable number of decades.  use `ax.set_ylim(1, 30)` instead.

Answer (score 7):

The hist constructor accepts the `log` parameter.
You can do this:

```py
plt.hist(data, bins=bins, log=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

np.logspace returns bins in `[1-10]`, logarithmically spaced - in my case xx is a npvector >0 so the following code does the trick

```
logbins=np.max(xx)*(np.logspace(0, 1, num=1000) - 1)/9
hh,ee=np.histogram(xx, density=True, bins=logbins)
```

Answer (score 2):

[tacaswell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17952890/13543344) was correct, although the `nonposy` keyword argument has since been deprecated in favor of `nonpositive`. Furthermore, the link to the documentation is no longer active, please see the [current docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yscale) for more info.

Updated solution:

```
plt.yscale('log', nonpositive='clip')
```