# Plot histogram with x-axis not rendered when bins are logspaced

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot the histogram of an array elements. These elements values span over 10 orders (from `10^-10` to `1`). However, the range in which I am really interested is only `10^-10 - 10^-5`.

So I was thinking to plot the histogram on a log x-axis. I followed these two discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855710/how-to-have-logarithmic-bins-in-a-python-histogram) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952279/logarithmic-y-axis-bins-in-python).

In the first case:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(size=10000)
pl.hist(data, bins=np.logspace(0.1, 1.0, 50))
pl.gca().set_xscale("log")
```

the plot is not rendered. The axis are showed clearly but no histogram appears on the plot.
If I substitute the `bins=np.logspace(0.1, 1.0, 50)` with a simple value, let's say `100`, the plot is showed correctly.

In the second discussion:

```
plt.xscale('log', nonposy='clip')
```

I don't know how to specify the number of bins in the selected x-range: the software automatically spread the specified number of bins over the whole range of values in the array.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your example seems to render fine for me. Which version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: Please note that the code I reported is only a quote from the linked discussions. As I said, my values and the range where I want to plot them are very different from the example.