# Separated caps in the errorbar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a plot with `xerror` and `yerror`, but for some of the points in my plot, the `yerror` caps are separated from the points.

I don't know why it happens, any suggestion?

My data:

```
9.25E-008   1.16E-009   9.47E-009   3.58E-010   
1.68E-007   1.25E-009   9.37E-009   3.25E-010   
1.95E-007   7.06E-010   1.36E-009   1.65E-010   
7.49E-007   1.42E-009   1.27E-007   3.36E-010   
1.38E-007   4.55E-010   5.54E-009   1.11E-010   
9.93E-007   7.52E-009   6.62E-008   1.83E-009   
1.31E-006   1.21E-008   3.13E-007   3.07E-009   
1.14E-006   9.10E-009   7.73E-008   2.27E-009   
2.04E-006   1.11E-008   6.91E-008   2.75E-009   
1.10E-006   1.34E-008   1.26E-007   4.26E-009   
1.75E-007   5.84E-009   2.90E-007   1.37E-009   
9.32E-008   5.92E-009   4.29E-008   1.16E-009   
2.96E-007   7.10E-009   1.23E-007   1.95E-009   
8.27E-007   1.14E-008   8.67E-008   3.19E-009   
7.11E-007   9.26E-009   5.17E-009   2.15E-009   
1.00E-005   1.55E-008   3.55E-007   3.41E-009   
1.78E-006   4.31E-009   5.71E-008   7.84E-010   
5.45E-007   1.15E-008   1.03E-008   2.82E-009   
2.06E-008   8.45E-009   5.26E-008   1.85E-009   
6.88E-006   1.30E-008   6.02E-007   2.06E-009   
8.32E-006   1.16E-008   8.26E-008   3.00E-009   
1.45E-006   3.11E-009   2.02E-008   5.48E-010   
2.89E-007   4.70E-009   1.13E-007   1.09E-009   
1.92E-007   5.21E-009   5.60E-010   1.62E-009   
7.78E-006   1.86E-008   1.71E-009   3.46E-009   
5.41E-007   8.36E-009   1.07E-007   2.06E-009   
2.40E-007   2.84E-009   3.29E-008   5.20E-010   
5.37E-007   2.57E-008   2.19E-007   6.36E-009   
2.71E-007   2.99E-008   2.71E-009   8.52E-009   
3.48E-006   1.72E-008   7.01E-008   3.51E-009
```

My piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
data=np.genfromtxt("Plot.txt",unpack=True).T

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.errorbar(data[:,0],data[:,2],xerr=data[:,1],yerr=data[:,3], fmt= '.',color='red',capsize=5, elinewidth=1)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

plt.savefig("Plot.pdf")
```

[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you add your resulting plot?

Comment: @YuliaV Unfortunately not because I am a newbie and don't have enough reputation to post my plot.

Comment: are you sure you need reputation points to add a picture? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: @YuliaV I posted my plot.

Comment: What do you mean by "separated"? I don't see anything strange in your plot.

Comment: @skytux There are three points with yerrors caps far from the plotted points.

Comment: 1. Try to only output the faulty points, or reduce the number of healthy points as much as you can. 2. Try another output format if possible (e.g. jpeg).

Comment: The issue is that you are getting negative values for val-err.  This makes the bottom edge of the vertical bar 'nan' and hence the line dose not show up (as it only has one plottable point).  There is a setting to clip y-values instead of converting to nan.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952279/logarithmic-y-axis-bins-in-python/17952890#17952890

Comment: The three error bars are shown in my plot. But, I don't know why it is different from yours.