# Barplot with log y-axis program syntax with matplotlib pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror, bar-chart

I realize that this question has been asked before([Python Pyplot Bar Plot bars disappear when using log scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047068/python-pyplot-bar-plot-bars-disapear-when-using-log-scale)), but the answer given did not work for me. I set my pyplot.bar(x_values, y_values, etc, log = True) but got an error that says:

```
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'"
```

I have been searching in vain for an actual example of pyplot code that uses a bar plot with the y-axis set to log but haven't found it. What am I doing wrong?

here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig = pyplot.figure()
x_axis = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_axis = [334, 350, 385, 40000.0, 167000.0, 1590000.0]
ax.bar(x_axis, y_axis, log = 1)
pyplot.show()
```

I get an error even when I removre pyplot.show. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: show use the _full_ traceback please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised due to the `log = True` statement in `ax.bar(...`. I'm unsure if this a matplotlib bug or it is being used in an unintended way. It can easily be fixed by removing the offending argument `log=True`.

This can be simply remedied by simply logging the y values yourself.

```
x_values = np.arange(1,8, 1)
y_values = np.exp(x_values)

log_y_values = np.log(y_values)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(x_values,log_y_values) #Insert log=True argument to reproduce error
```

Appropriate labels `log(y)` need to be adding to be clear it is the log values.

Comment: The problem is that the bars are not filled in when I set the y_axis to log

Comment: I have addressed these points in an edit. I admit it is not as pretty as logging the x axis but it is still true that the error comes from the `log=True` argument.

Comment: I guess I could manually set the axis labels-this works as a stop gap but I am still confused as to why the log=True gives me the error.

Comment: Justin this must be a bug with matplotlib, I have just retried this with matplotlib 1.3 on my work computer and `log=True` works fine. What version are you using, it is perhaps worth [installing 1.3](http://matplotlib.org/dev/faq/installing_faq.html#installation).

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure that is all your code does? Where does the code throw the error? During plotting? Because this works for me:

```
In [16]: import numpy as np
In [17]: x = np.arange(1,8, 1)
In [18]: y = np.exp(x)

In [20]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [21]: fig = plt.figure()
In [22]: ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
In [24]: ax.bar(x, y, log=1)
Out[24]: 
[<matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x3cb1550>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x40598d0>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x4059d10>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x40681d0>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x4068650>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x4068ad0>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x4068f50>]
In [25]: plt.show()
```

Here's the plot
[image]

Comment: The code throws in the error when it reaches ax.bar(x, y, log=1). For some reason its still not working

Answer (score 4):

As already suggested in the comments to Greg's answer, you're indeed seeing an issue that was [fixed in matplotlib 1.3](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2147) by setting the default behavior to 'clip'. Upgrading to 1.3 fixes the issue for me.

Note that it doesn't seem to matter how you apply the log scale, whether as a keyword argument to `bar` or via `set_yscale` on the axis.

See also [this answer to "Logarithmic y-axis bins in python"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17952890) that suggests this workaround:

```
plt.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
```